# Postgres select query with offset for large table taking too much time to process

Tags: postgresql

To process a table having 3 million rows, I am using the following query in psql:

```
select id, trans_id, name
from omx.customer 
where user_token is null 
order by id, trans_id l
imit 1000 offset 200000000
```

It's taking more than 3 min to fetch the data. How to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that to know which 1000 records to fetch the database actually has to fetch all of the 200000000 records to count them.

The main strategy to combat this problem is to use a where clause instead of the offset.

If you know the previous 1000 rows (because this is some kind of iteratively used query) you can instead take the id and trans_id from the last row of that set and fetch the 1000 rows following it.

If the figure of 200000000 doesn't need to be exact and you can make a good guess of where to start then that might be an avenue to attack the problem.